# How get the id from codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have written a query in Codeigniter controller but i am not sure how to use the variable from the database.

Controller:

```
 $query = $this->partner_vs_skill_model->where('partner_id',$id )
                                       ->like('skill_id', $value)->get_all();    
 $row = count($query);
```

What I expect is to use the code like below

```
 echo $query->id;
```

Database table (partner_vs_skill_model):

```
id | partner_id | skill_id 
1  |  2         | 3 
2  |  5         | 4
```

Comment: what u exactly want to achieve pls specify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*For One row use `row(`), like :*

```
$query = $this->partner_vs_skill_model->where('partner_id',$id )
                                      ->like('skill_id', $value)->row();
echo $query->id;
echo $query->skill_id;
```

*For multiple rows use `result()` instead, like :*

```
$query = $this->partner_vs_skill_model->where('partner_id',$id )
                                      ->like('skill_id', $value)->result();
```

Access it like this :

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
  echo $row->id;
  echo $row->skill_id;
}
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Comment: tq very much from my current code I try to do like this and it work foreach ($query as $row) { $s = $row['id']; }

Comment: since you are returning data as array so use it like this `$s = $row['id']`; i am returning as object so i use this way

Answer (score 1):

In example:
// controller-part:

```
 $query = $this->partner_vs_skill_model->get_partner_skill();
 echo $query;
```

// model"

```
<?php
      class partner_vs_sill_model extends CI_Model{
       public function get_partner_skill(){
        $result = $this->db->get('tb_name')->row_array();
        return $result
         }
      }
```

Comment: tq very much from my current code I try to do like this and it work foreach ($query as $row) { $s = $row['id']; }

Answer (score 0):

you are getting an array of results to $query variable. what I am suggesting is to use below kind of code snippet to loop through the result and get the skill_tag variable

```
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo $row->skill_tag
}
```

Comment: tq very much I try to do like this and it work   foreach ($query as $row) {
      $s = $row['id'];
     }